# Unable to understand the logic behind treesorting in this particular case of mine

Tags: java, collections, comparable, treeset

I have the following "Person" `class` -

```
import java.rmi.activation.ActivationGroup_Stub;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private int marks;
    private String name;

    Person(int marks, String name) {
        this.marks = marks;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person: Marks = " + marks + ", Name =  " + name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        int myReturn = 0;
        if (marks > person.marks) {
            myReturn = 1;
        } else if (marks < person.marks) {
            myReturn = -1;
        } else {
            int minLength = 0;
            boolean equal = false;
            if (name.length() < person.name.length()) {
                minLength = name.length();
            } else if (name.length() > person.name.length()) {
                minLength = person.name.length();
             } else {
                minLength = name.length();
                equal = true;
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
                if (i == minLength) {
                    if (equal) {
                        myReturn = 0;
                        break;
                    } else if (name.length() > minLength) {
                        myReturn = 1;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        myReturn = -1;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if(name.charAt(i) > person.name.charAt(i)) {
                    myReturn = 1;
                    break;
                } else if (name.charAt(i) < person.name.charAt(i)) {
                    myReturn = -1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return myReturn;
    }
}
```

Now in main class I have made the `TreeClass` -

```
TreeSet<Person> treeSet1 = new TreeSet<>(List.of(
                new Person(67, "Nusrat"),
                new Person(67, "Nusrat"),
                new Person(67, "Nupur"),
                new Person(72, "Nupur"),
                new Person(67, "Nupur"),
                new Person(67, "Nipun"),
                new Person( 67, "Nipuna"),
                new Person(67, "Jhilam")
        ));
```

Upon printing the output is -

```
Person: Marks = 67, Name =  Jhilam
Person: Marks = 67, Name =  Nipun
Person: Marks = 67, Name =  Nupur
Person: Marks = 67, Name =  Nusrat
Person: Marks = 72, Name =  Nupur
```

All is right except "Nipun" and "Nipuna" are considered as equal. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; you sort by `marks` first, which is reflected in the output, and "Nipuna" *does* come after "Nipun". Put another way: why *wouldn't* Nipuna be where it is in the list?

Comment: I mean as per my logic Nipuna should come after Nipun, and not after Nupur

Comment: Why? Nippuna's marks are greater than both Nipun's and Nupur's. That is how `compareTo` is written: the only time alphabetical order matters if if their marks are the same.

Comment: Silly me , I am so sorry, for all the trouble

Comment: @DaveNewton byt in that case Nipun vanished from list as if "Nipun and Nipuna are duplicate"

Comment: You'll have to debug your `compareTo` logic then.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, it was a logical error in the for loops -

the correct code would be -

```
for (int i = 1; i <= minLength; i++)
```

Now output as expected  -

```
Person: Marks = 67, Name =  Jasmine
Person: Marks = 67, Name =  Jhilam
Person: Marks = 67, Name =  Nipun
Person: Marks = 67, Name =  Nipuna
Person: Marks = 67, Name =  Nupur
Person: Marks = 67, Name =  Nusrat
Person: Marks = 72, Name =  Nupur
```

Comment: The string’s characters still start at index zero. Changing the start index to one did not solve anything. Using `i <= minLength` as end condition fixes your issue as it ensures that the `if (i == minLength)` part may get executed when all characters matched so far, however, it would be much cleaner to place this code after the loop, as what should happen after iterating over the characters doesn’t belong into the loop over the characters at all. Besides that, why don’t you use `name.compareTo(person.name)` instead of reinventing string comparison?